# NFC: NTAG 424 DNA TT authentication - application tips needed

Tags: authentication, encryption, nfc

I've these chips NXP NTAG 424 DNA TT. I've set them up (SUN + mirroring) using Android app NFC TagWriter by NXP. I am missing one crucial detail. Some operations, like loading an application key into the chip, require the writer to authenticate. I haven't found an app which is able to perform these actions which need authorized writer. Any tips for an (Android) app which I can use to change the application keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a Type 4 NFC Card, while it is configured with the Industry standard Application ID (AID) for Ndef data storage initially, there is so much more non standard stuff if can do that unless somebody has written a specific application to do all the stuff then it it unlikely for you to do what you want.

You will probably have to write the Android Application yourself to issues the specific commands you want via [IsoDep](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep) API

Comment: I guess you are right, so I accept your answer. Thanks for pointing me the way.